# Javascript validations not working. No alert is being raised

Tags: javascript, validation

No alert is being raised while running this code. It is not working. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:
I have also tried to document.formname.value but still no result.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
    <title>Regestration form</title>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script >
function validate()

{
    if (document.getElementsByName(fname) = "")
    {
        alert (" please enter first name ");

        return false ;

        }
    if (document.getElementsByName(lname) = "")
    {
        alert (" please enter last name ");

        return false ;

        }
    if (document.getElementsByName('gen') = "")
    {
        alert (" please select gender ");

        return false ;

        }

{   
var eid = documnet.getElementsByName(email);
var atpos = eid.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = eid.lastIndexOf(".");
}
    if (document.getElementsByName(email)= "" ||atpos < 1 || (atpos-dotpos < 2)
    {
        alert (" please enter a valid email ");

        return false ;

        }
    if (document.getElementsByName(pass1) = "" || document.getElementsByName(pass1) < 6)
    {
        alert (" Please enter atleast 6 digit password ");

        return false ;

        }
    if (document.getElementsByName(pass1)!= document.getElementsByName(pass2))
    {
        alert ("password do not match");

        return false ;
    }
}
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    require 'formprocessor.php';


    ?>
    <div id="frm">
    <div id="fhead">
    <h3>Registeration Form</h3>
    </div>
    <form method="post" name="regfrm" action="formprocessor.php" onsubmit="return validate();" >
    <div class="name">First Name</div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" name="fname"  placeholder="Enter First Name"/> <span><?php echo $errfn ?></span></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="name">Last Name</div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" /><span><?php echo $errln ?></span></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div  class="name">Gender</div>
    <div class="input"> <input type="radio" name="gen" value="male" />Male
                        <input type="radio" name="gen" value="female"/>Female
    <span><?php echo $errgn ?></span></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="name">Email</div>
    <div class="input"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Valid Email"/><span><?php echo $errem ?></span></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="name">Password</div>
    <div class="input"><input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Minimum 6 character password"/><span><?php echo $errp1 ?></span></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="name">Confirm Password</div>
    <div class="input"><input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Same password as Above"/><span><?php echo $errp2 ?></span></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="sub" > <input type="submit" value="Register Now!" name="sub"  /></div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is your `validate` function definition?

Comment: I think we need to see `formprocessor.php`.

Comment: please show your entire code. Where is the JS that validates the form?

Comment: where is your javascript validation part? is this your full code to validate?

Comment: have updated the JS code . formprocessor.php just contain the Db connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (document.getElementsByName(email)= "" ||atpos < 1 || (atpos-dotpos < 2)
```

in this you have a bracket ) missing at the end . use editors like notepad++ for checking it.

and

```
{var eid = documnet.getElementsByName(email);var atpos = eid.indexOf("@");var dotpos =eid.lastIndexOf(".");}
```

no need of {}  here this just add

```
var eid = documnet.getElementsByName(email);var atpos = eid.indexOf("@");var dotpos = id.lastIndexOf(".");
```

finaly

replace all`document.getElementsByName(lname)`  to `document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value`

change the name accordingly with correct one is filed in quotes document.getElementsByName("fname") returns an array of elements with name "fname" since we have only one field with that name we chose document.getElementsByName("fname")[0] the first index of array.now we got the first filed. now we have to fetch value from it using document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value

study more about the basics of javascript and html from http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: what if i use document.formname.feildname.value

Comment: you cant use it directly first
 you have to get form by id or name  to a var  
var form document.getElementById("myForm");
then you can use form.fname.value
document.getElementById("myForm").fname.value is also valid but not a good practice